# Pq a barra de navegação está se sobrepondo no header?

Tags: css, css3

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como vocês podem ver a barra de navegação está cobrindo o header(que o banner como background), porém em teoria (com base nos meus conhecimentos, é claro) o header deveria começar logo após a nav.

OBS: Tentei dar um margin-top no header só para testar e a nav desceu junto com ele. Tentei usar z-index e continuou na mesma.

Enfim, aí está o meu código HTML e CSS, respectivamente:

HTML:

```
<nav>
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="nav-main">
            <ul>
                <li>Início</li>
                <li>Organização</li>
                <li>Parceiros</li>
                <li>Programação</li>
                <li>Hospedagem</li>
                <li>Trabalhos Cientifícos</li>
            </ul>   
        </div>
        <div class="inscreva-nav">
            <button>Inscreva-se</button>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <header></header>
```

CSS:

```
/*barra de navegação*/

nav {
    height: 124px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #c4322e;
    position: fixed;
    opacity: 0.6;
    display: block;
}

.logo{
    height: 124px;
    width: 205px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.logo img{
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 2.2rem;
}

.nav-main{
    display: inline-block;
}

nav ul{
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    color: white;
}

nav li{
    font-size: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 33px;
}

.inscreva-nav {
    float: right;
}

nav button {
    font-size: 30px;
    width: 285px;
    height: 62px;
    background: none;
    border: solid white 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: white;
    margin-top: 1.8rem;
    margin-right: 23px;
}

/*barra de navegação - fim */

/* header*/
header{
    background: url(../img/teaser.jpg) no-repeat fixed; 
    width: 100%;
    height: 464px;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como o nav tem posição fixed você precisa colocar um top no header igual a altura do nav.

```
header {
    position: relative;
    top: 124px;
}
```

Comment: Eu tinha tentado tirar o fixed da nav, mas continuava a mesma coisa. Mas deu certo, nem parei pra pensar nisso. Muito obrigado, cara!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar um `float: left` no `header` e dar um `margin-top: 124px;`

```css
/*barra de navegação*/

nav {
    height: 124px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #c4322e;
    position: fixed;
    opacity: 0.6;
    display: block;
}

.logo{
    height: 124px;
    width: 205px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.logo img{
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 2.2rem;
}

.nav-main{
    display: inline-block;
}

nav ul{
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    color: white;
}

nav li{
    font-size: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 33px;
}

.inscreva-nav {
    float: right;
}

nav button {
    font-size: 30px;
    width: 285px;
    height: 62px;
    background: none;
    border: solid white 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: white;
    margin-top: 1.8rem;
    margin-right: 23px;
}

/*barra de navegação - fim */

/* header*/
header{
    background: url(../img/teaser.jpg) no-repeat fixed; 
    width: 100%;
    height: 464px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 134px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="nav-main">
            <ul>
                <li>Início</li>
                <li>Organização</li>
                <li>Parceiros</li>
                <li>Programação</li>
                <li>Hospedagem</li>
                <li>Trabalhos Cientifícos</li>
            </ul>   
        </div>
        <div class="inscreva-nav">
            <button>Inscreva-se</button>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <header>dsada</header>
```